# Search for RSS Feeds on Google

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, google-search

I hope I am not just chasing a red herring here. I have seen some websites that you are able to search for RSS feeds by typing in some sort of term like "Technology news" and it would return a number of different feeds that you can chose from.
Most look to be where they are just searching their own curated database which is all fine and dandy, however there is one that looks like it uses Google to search for them. http://ctrlq.org/rss/

Does anyone know how this could be done and point me in the right direction to learn how it is done as it is bugging the life out of me? I have done a lot of searching but most seem to point to the depreciated Google Feed API that no longer works or using Google Alerts to create an RSS Feed which I am not wanting to do.

Ideally I would like to do this in C# so that I can easily deal with the results and save the relevant selected option in a database.

It also doesn't need to be Google that it is done in, if there are other options that are available then great :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was kinda intrigue by your question and this is what I've find out. First of all I went to the site http://ctrlq.org/rss/ and checked what is done after click on Search button:

```
function findfeeds() {      
      var q = $.trim($('#feedQuery').val());
      if(q == "") {
          resetfeeds();
          return false;
      }

      $('#pleasewait').show();   

      google.feeds.findFeeds(q, function(result) {
      if (!result.error) {
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entries.length; i++) {
          var entry = result.entries[i];
          feedList[i] = entry.url;
          var count = i+1;
          html += '<div id="feed-' + i + '">';
          html += ' <h3><img src="//s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + entry.link + '"/> <a target="_blank" href="' + entry.link + '">' + removeHTMLTags(entry.title) + '</a></h3>';
          html += ' <p class="snippet">' + removeHTMLTags(entry.contentSnippet) + '</p>';
          html += ' <p class="feedURL">';
          html += '<a href="' + entry.url + '" target="_blank">RSS Feed</a> &sdot; ';
          html += ' <span class="showhide" rel="' + i + '">Preview Feed</span></p>';
          html += ' <div id="feedcontent-' + i + '"></div>';
          html += '</div>';
        }

        $("#results").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
            $("#results").empty();
            $("#results").append(html);
            $("#results").show();
        });     
       }
            $('#pleasewait').hide();   
    });
      return false;
    }
```

This is the function called after click. I noticed it uses something named 'google.feeds.findFeeds' so a bit of searching and voilà: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#optional. There is a google api which provides functionality for searching and browsing public rss feeds :)  The site provides examples of use so you can read more there. I hope this covers all of your doubts ;)

Comment: Ah cool thanks @Lesmain, so the Google Feeds API is still working? When I go on the page it says that it is depreciated, I just assumed that it mean that it was no longer working.

Comment: Been playing around and have managed to get something working :D Awesome, thank you very much for the help @Lesmain. Slightly annoyed that I just assumed that they stopped working because it was depreciated. Guessing I just need to hope that they don't get rid of it all together anytime soon. Once I am allowed to reward the bounty, it will be coming your way :)

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you @ian_mac123 ;) I've never used google feed api, but some says that you can use Yahoo's YQL API as some kind of alternative.

Comment: Yeah I believe YQL might be more for parsing feeds that you already know about rather than searching for new ones, but I will need to read more up on it just in case it can be a viable alternative if Google finally shuts down theirs. Thanks again for the help, bounty has been rewarded :)

Comment: This API is officially deprecated and will stop working after September 29th, 2016. See our deprecation policy in our Terms of Service for details. :(